# How do I get shaped bokeh without a Lensbaby?

Tags: accessories, bokeh, lensbaby, shaped-bokeh

Is there a good hardware solution for generating shaped bokeh?  I know Lensbaby has a set of filters that give various shapes — is there a similar solution for other lens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Bokeh Masters Kit

Available here: http://www.bokehmasterskit.com/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Now I wonder if it's worth the $25 to have someone else cut the holes.

Comment: It's not, get a rubber band, cut the stencils yourself in a few minutes. You can buy shaped hole punches to make different shapes easier.

Answer (score 19):

Just cut a hole in a piece of paper, and tape it over a wide-aperture lens? See, for instance, [this link](http://digital-photography-school.com/forum/how-i-took/33858-shaped-bokeh.html) and [this link](http://www.diyphotography.net/diy_create_your_own_bokeh).

Comment: Yea, I've done this.  Looking to se if there is a more "manufactured" and less "D.I.Y" solution.

Comment: As far as I can see, all the "manufactured" solutions amount to having somebody _else_ cut a hole in a piece of paper (or, more likely, in a plastic lens cap). The lensbaby "creative apertures kit" is pretty much exactly that, by the look of it.

Comment: Well, *technically* the Lensbaby ones are metal, but that's just because the tool to remove them from the system is a magnet. :)